Commonly requested character identifications!
Got a trinket that has one or two decorative Chinese characters on it? Can't figure out what it says? Before you click that big ol' Ask Question button, please check out some commonly requested identifications here, as we don't do character identification or translation requests, unless prior research effort has been shown.
This is a work in progress, so if your character doesn't show up, don't panic! The community will point you in the right direction, and we will add the character to this page if it becomes a frequently requested character.

This is my attempt at addressing https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/character-identification-page - suggestions/corrections welcome, and also suggest characters that we need to put on this page. My next target is「福」.

功德無量 :) would you include these : 之, 印, 寶 & characters of 10 天干, 12 地支

@水巷孑蠻 yes okay, sounds good. you're right, they occur alot on paintings

thanks, i must confess that i'm idiot in handling photos / pictures.

「壽」(longevity)

Orthodox character
　

Glyph evolution sequence and older variants
　　　　　　

Core character components (for non-cursive characters)
If you've managed to spot at least both of these components in your character, regardless of whether other components are present, chances are you're looking at「壽」.

Top component:「耂」(ignore greyed out part)
　　　　　
Bottom component:「」
　　　


Regular script variants
Common
　　　
More variants (including some common variants above)


Seal script samples


Cursive script samples


Special mentions

Round seals, based on adding「耂」to its own vertically flipped mirror image
　

(from Google image search)
Diagram of a hundred「壽」(Google image search)


Character structure
西周金蔡姞簋集成4198西周金對罍集成9826秦簡日書乙種75睡虎地秦簡篆老部・壽說文解字東漢隸羊竇道碑　今楷　
「壽」(Baxter-Sagart OC: /*[N-t]uʔ/, /*[N-t]uʔ-s/, longevity) is composed of semantic「耂」(picture of an old person with unkempt hair > old, elderly, now written「老」) and phonetic「」(/*[d]ru/). 「口」and/or「又」were optionally added to the character.
The modern form「壽」comes from the inclusion of both「口」and「又」, with「又」later slightly changing into「寸」. Also, both semantic「耂」and phonetic「」became heavily corrupted.

「」is a picture of a divided farmland, and this word is now written as「疇」.
商甲甲2124合集339


Example questions

Only two characters but I have no idea what they signify
What does this symbol mean on my ring?
What characters are on this ceramic jar?
What are the characters on this?


References and image sources

國學大師
小學堂
中國哲學書電子化計劃
教育部異體字字典
中華語文知識庫


「福」(fortune, blessing, happiness)

Orthodox character
　

Sample of older variants and regular script counterparts

「福」+「宀」
　　
「福」+「宀」+「玉」
　　
「福」, replacing「畐」with「北」
　　
「福」+「北」
　　


Core character components (for non-cursive characters)
「畐」(or some minor shape change from「畐」) is the most important component. If it isn't present, you're unlikely to be looking at「福」, although rare exceptions do exist (like the third form of the above section).「示」is the second most important component; if「宀」is present, without「示」the character is not「福」but「富」(wealthy) instead.

「畐」
　　　　
「示・礻」(a lot of variants for this one!)
　　　　　　　　


Regular script variants


Seal script samples


Cursive script samples


Special mentions

「福」may deliberately appear upside-down (see Why 福 is often used upside down?).

Round seals. Stare at it closely and the resemblance to「福」should be evident; cut the join at the bottom of the character to separate it into the left and right sides. The top of the character is stylised to make the left and right sides appear symmetrical.

(from Google image search)
Diagram of a hundred「福」(Google image search)


Character structure
西周金士父鐘集成145篆示部・福說文解字秦簡秦律十八66睡虎地秦簡今楷　
「福」(Baxter-Sagart OC: /*pək/, good fortune/blessing) is composed of semantic「示」(ancestral tablet, here indicating religious prayer rituals) and phonetic「畐」(/*[b]ək/).

The older variants have not survived. These are, specifically,

Additions of「宀」and「玉」, might be referring to「寶」(treasure) in the wealth fortune aspect (now clearly written as「富」)
西周金B311鼎集成2280春秋・邾金邾大宰鐘集成86
Addition of「北」(/*pˤək/) or replacement of「畐」with「北」.「北」serves as an additional or alternative phonetic component
西周金周乎卣集成5406西周金者鼎集成2662



Example questions

Only two characters but I have no idea what they signify
What characters are on this ceramic jar?
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68792/does-this-kanji-stamp-actually-mean-harmony


References and image sources

國學大師
小學堂
中國哲學書電子化計劃
教育部異體字字典

